# Are the builtins the only functions that can accept a type parameter?

Tags: go, built-in

The `make` function takes a type parameter.

i.e. `make([]int, 3)`

Is this just a special syntax for builtins or can we create functions that take types (without reflection of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you cannot.

They are special cases. The `builtin` package is there purely for documentation purposes .. there is no actual way for you to accept a type parameter like that. You may have already seen that Go does not support generics.

Comment: Correct. "For documentation purposes only" comes from [this description](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#Type).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a built-in only syntax.

Even in the documented source, they note that the in `func make(Type, size IntegerType) Type` the 
`Type` parameter is just a stand-in for any Go-type and is only explicitly stated for documentation purposes only.

Source: https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go